# why i didnt could started with the band?

Tags: microsoft-band

im having problems with the installation of the nuget packets for the microsoft band sdk, im using visual studio 2015, in a pc of 64 bits, i have a warning:

> could not install package microsoft.band 1.3.10702.you are trying to
>   install this package into in a a project that targets NETFramework,
>   Version=v3.5, but the package does not contain any assembly references
>   or content files that are compatible with the framework,for more
>   information contact the package author.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

The Band SDK supports only Windows (Store) 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 applications.  It cannot be used with a Windows (desktop) application or one that targets an older version of the .NET Framework (such as v3.5).

Comment: how i start this project in visual studio?